# Calling a WCF service from Java

Tags: c#, wcf

**EDIT:** the issue was with the `[MessageHeader]` attributes in the `ResponseMessage` class; Metro/JAX-WS doesn't seem capable of handling these attributes. Changing them to `[MessageBodyMember]` solved the issue.

---

As the title says, I need to get some Java 1.5 code to call a WCF web service. I've downloaded and used [Metro](https://metro.dev.java.net/2.0/) to generate Java proxy classes, but they aren't generating what I expect, and I believe this is because of the WSDL that the WCF service generates.

My WCF classes look like this (full code omitted for brevity):

```
public class TestService : IService
{
  public TestResponse DoTest(TestRequest request)
  {
    TestResponse response = new TestResponse();

    // actual testing code...

    response.Result = ResponseResult.Success;

    return response;
  }
}

public class TestResponse : ResponseMessage
{
  public bool TestSucceeded { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseMessage
{
  [MessageHeader]
  public ResponseResult Result { get; set; }

  [MessageHeader]
  public string ResponseDesc { get; set; }

  [MessageHeader]
  public Guid ErrorIdentifier { get; set; }
}

public enum ResponseResult
{
  Success,
  Error,
  Empty,
}
```

and the resulting WSDL (when I browse to http://localhost/TestService?wsdl=wsdl0) looks like this:

```
<xsd:element name="TestResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="TestSucceeded" type="xsd:boolean" /> 
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ErrorIdentifier" type="q1:guid" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" /> 
<xsd:simpleType name="ResponseResult">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:enumeration value="Error" /> 
<xsd:enumeration value="Success" /> 
<xsd:enumeration value="EmptyResult" /> 
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:element name="ResponseResult" nillable="true" type="tns:ResponseResult" /> 
<xsd:element name="Result" type="tns:ResponseResult" /> 
<xsd:element name="ResultDesc" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />

...

<xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid" /> 
<xs:simpleType name="guid">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}" /> 
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Immediately I see an issue with this WSDL: `TestResponse` does not contain the properties inherited from `ResponseMessage`. Since this service has always worked in Visual Studio I've never questioned this before, but maybe that could be causing my problem?

Anyhow, when I run Metro's `wsimport.bat` on the service the following error message is generated:

`[WARNING] src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'q1:guid'`

and the outputted Java version of `TestResponse` lacks any of the properties from `ResponseMessage`.

I hacked the WSDL a bit and changed `ErrorIdentifier` to be typed as `xsd:string`, which makes the message about resolving the GUID type go away, but I still don't get any of `ResponseMessage`'s properties.

Finally, I altered the WSDL to include the 3 properties from `ResponseMessage` in `TestResponse`, and of course the end result is that the generated .java file contains them. However, when I actually call the WCF service from Java, those 3 properties are always `null`.

Any advice, apart from writing the proxy classes myself?

Comment: Can you please help me finding how, downloading, and using Metro ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some #%$^@! changed the `[MessageBodyMember]` attributes on the properties of `ResponseMessage` to `[MessageHeader]` without telling anyone. I changed them back to `[MessageBodyMember]`, regenerated the proxy classes and everything works correctly.

Onced I've finished the integration I'll be doing CVS diffs to find the person responsible, and then they shall SUFFER MY WRATH.

Comment: glad you found the problem; +1 for posting it. Please update your question to show the true attributes, otherwise it will confuse future readers. You should also accept your own answer.

Comment: That is no solution. If there is already a member with the MessageBodyMember attribute applied, you gonna receive a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with Java, but only with the WSDL being generated.

Why are you not using `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` on your TestResponse and ResponseMessage classes? Try that and see if it works.

Comment: All the requisite attributes are present, but I omitted them to make my post shorter. As my answer shows, that was probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I do not mean to be glib or reject Java-native solutions out of hand, but when it comes to the Wcf stack, the best advice is typically to *use* the Wcf stack.

More to the point: generate a CLR Wcf client [in language of choice auto-generate client via VS or svcutil against static wsdl or service endpoint] and then invoke this CLR proxy through some Java-CLR interop.

There are several reasons for this, not the least of which

- Immediate compliance [by Wcf for Wcf]
- Flexibility [it is not unreasonable to expect your remote service to change or leverage sophisticated communication protocols, such as message-level encryption, you want your client to change as easily as the service]

---

ps: I have strong misgivings about modifying existing service wsdls by hand. If the wsdl is indeed "the problem", then this indicates either a problem with service definition [ie server-side code] or service interpretation [ie an option on autogeneration utility]. Avoid manual manipulations of service contracts. Doing so would be like modifying IL byte code post-build.

Comment: I'm completely with you regarding editing WSDL to make things work - it's just that I was running out of time and options and was willing to try anything to make things work. :)

Comment: I don't agree we have got both java calling wcf and wcf calling java web service with both message security and two-way ssl security working very successfully (without modifying WSDL). This is for real multi-million dollar commercial scenario. Metro is the best java stack to interoperate with WCF services.