# Calling a WCF service from Java, redux

Tags: wcf, soap, jax-ws

[Calling a WCF service from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015124/calling-a-wcf-service-from-java)

Following on from the above question, does anyone know how to get `wsimport` to see WCF properties marked with the `[MessageHeader]` attribute, and hence generate fields for said properties on the generated Java proxy classes?

Unfortunately the requirement has now come up (from another vendor, le sigh) to use `[MessageHeader]` as well as `[MessageBodyMember]` and as a result the Java interop is breaking - which is making me a Sad Panda™. And nobody wants that.

Comment: Found a solution already? Running into the same problem, a Vendor having a WCF based webservice with MessageHeader tagged fields in message contracts which I need to call from Java EE.