# Creating a Java Proxy for a .NET based webservice with Message Contracts with MessageHeader attributes on fields

Tags: wcf, jakarta-ee, wsdl, jax-ws, wsimport

I have a duplicate question of this unanswered question [Calling a WCF service from Java, redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987775/calling-a-wcf-service-from-java-redux?stw=2) from a few years ago.

I want to generate a Java proxy for a webservice provided by a partner company.
The webservice was made in .NET. It uses message contracts with MessageHeader attributes on some fields The contract cannot be changed.

The Java proxy generator, wsimport, seems to ignore the Fields tagged with MessageHeader.  How to get this solved?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem recently, I have implmented [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) service between JAVA and .NET so my diagram was something like this:

Third Party <==> .Net Service  <==JSON ==> ActiveMQ <==JSON==> JAVA proxy service

Please note that .Net and JAVA proxy both talk to ActiveMQ in JSON messages in both directions. You may note that you will face some difficulties as the third party .Net objects may be difficult to de/serialize from/to JSON

Comment: If the service had a JSON api their would not be an issue.  It is SOAP/WCF complexity.

Comment: Please note that in my proposed structure you have to creat a NEW .Net Service to interact with the SOAP/WCF from one side and expose a NEW JSON interface from the other. you can argue that this requires more efforts, but it does work and it keeps you in control.

Comment: Not an option. I have no control over the partner webservice and we are not going to host .NET based code that runs a wcf<>json proxy. I used to be a .NET Developer but went back to the Duke side of the force. I Just want wsimport or something else generate a proper proxy.